# converting visual c++ array<char> to long

Tags: arrays, c++-cli

I want to read 8 byte from a file.

```
StreamReader^ sr = gcnew StreamReader( "ReadMe.txt" );
long convert = 0;
array<Char>^c = nullptr;

while ( sr->Peek() >= 0 )
{    
   c = gcnew array<Char>(8);

   sr->Read( c, 0, c->Length );

   convert = (long) c; //<- the problem

   Console::WriteLine( c );
   Console::WriteLine( convert ); 
}
```

but i get this output:

EA00A10C <- same as the file

37745844 <- wrong (even if convert dec to hex)

Note: 
atoi does not take the type array, i did not found a array.ToInt function ...

Comment: `Console::WriteLine` doesn't process arrays in any sensible way, so I think it's your first result that's wrong.

Comment: i checked the output of the fist against the file and it is correct , and this is visual c++ as told in the tag

Comment: Oh, it's an array of `Char`, not `char`.  And there's an overload for it.  But please don't do that.  Write `System.Char` or `wchar_t`, either one is MUCH less subject to confusion than `Char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for

```
System::Int32::Parse(c, NumberStyles::HexNumber)
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx only works with strings - i got an error

Comment: @Thomas, then use `Parse(gcnew String(c), NumberStyles::HexNumber)`

Comment: could you edit the answer with your correct comment ? but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one? (:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c36yw7x9(v=vs.80).aspx

Example:

float f = 3.3;
int n = static_cast(f);

Answer (score 0):

You try to convert a pointer to a long simply by casting. However, you need to convert a character-array (textual representation of a number) to a numeric value.

The `System::Int32::Parse(c, NumberStyles::HexNumber)` from Ben Voigt will do.

Basically, this is the same as

```
convert = strtol(&c[0], &c[7], 16);
```

Comment: .... except that to call `strtol`, you need to use `pin_ptr`, or else the garbage collector might move the array while you're reading it

Comment: I don't think, that the gc will happen while the gcptr is still within the active scope, but he shouldn't use those low-level C-Functions anyway. Your solution is the better one, I just tried to explain, what the error was ;)